# Monitor updates of application cache in Firefox

Tags: firefox, listener, application-cache

I have a web app which uses application cache. I want to *show progress* of populating the cache after manifest is changed.

Event handler `applicationCache.onprogress` is used to monitor the progress of file downloads.

This *works* on Google Chrome and Safari: event `onprogress` is being generated per each file after the file is downloaded.
However on Firefox all onprogress events are generated at the beginning - right after the main html page is loaded - *before* any file referenced from manifest is downloaded to the cache.

That prevents me from displaying file downloads progress. What is the proper way to monitor downloading of files to application cache in Firefox?

Version of Firefox: 24 on Linux Mint.
Thanks for help.

---

**SOLUTION:** progress monitoring actually works in Firefox, I was using too small number of cached files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox generates approximately 15 `progress` events immediately and others are fired gradually during populating the cache. My mistake, I was testing on ***small data set***.

Monitoring of progress works fine when there are for example 100 files listed in the manifest.